# cart with default product

Tags: product, cart

I would like to fill my cart with one virtual product by default (permanent).

It should work like this:
The user visits my shop. When he opens the empty cart, he should always find one article there. The article should be a virtual product as a present free of charge.

Has anybody an idea how to solve this in a simple way, or with an extension?

I tried so much, but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you Google on "magento autoadd" you will find a couple of extensions that should help you with that. They can add an extra 'gift' product to the cart whenever the customer adds a product.

The work on the same principal as cart promotional rules so you should be able to add your logic in the rule for the gift product.

Answer (score 1):

I checked out your suggestion, but unfortunately that does not work for my project.

I need the free product to be in the user´s cart without the condition, that he has to put in another product inside the cart first.

Could there be any other solution?